# Using MySQL source command to run script in text file

Tags: mysql

What I want to know is how to run code which I have put in a text file, in the MySQL command line client, using the SOURCE command.
(The text file I put the code in is called 'Testrun').

I know it starts by:

```
SOURCE C:\Users\Emily\Documents\MySQLpractice
```

but I don't know how to finish the command. I understand you have to put the file name afterwards, but is there a backslash, a forward slash or something else in-between that and the file path?

What's in the text file:

```
USE exams;
SELECT * FROM students;
```

I have tried to look up the answer before but people said different things each time, and I couldn't get anything to work.
Help is hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper syntax on windows is:

```
SOURCE C:/Users/Emily/Documents/MySQLpractice/File.sql;
```